# addColumn from relation table backpack laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In my project i have two tables for product object: products (where sku,price,available, etc...) and product_description (name,description, etc...).

Tables structure
products
https://prnt.sc/lu03kg

product_description
https://prnt.sc/lu0436

I try to add column by this code in ProductDescriptionCrudController.

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
'label' => 'Price',
'type' => 'number',
'name' => 'id',
'entity' => 'product',
'attribute' => 'price',
'model' => 'App\Models\Product'
]);
```

But I get the id of product. What i'm doing wrong?

The addField for price method work right

```
$this->crud->addfield([
'label' => 'Price',
'name' => 'price',
'tab' => 'Prices',
'type' => 'number',
'entity' => 'product',
'model' => 'App\Models\Product'
]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you used package?? for crud??

Comment: can you show `ProductDescriptionCrudController` whole content

Comment: It's package for admin panel.

Here is my ProductDescriptionController
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e-5Y5LhysJkZXhJFXq92TVWpvOnxwwKd

Answer (score 2):

I dont see in your "product_description" table a column for the relation to "products". Having that column in you ProductDescription model you might have:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RELATIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
}
```

So in the listing you specify with the "name" parameter the column for the relation:

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
        'name' => "product_id",
        'label' => "Product",
        'type' => "select",
        'entity' => "product",
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'model' => "App\Models\Product",
]);
```